forge test error
When I’m running:
forge test -- -m testPriceFeedVersionIsAccurate -vvv --fork-url (followed by my url)

It’s giving the following error:
error: unexpected argument 'testPriceFeedVersionIsAccurate' found



The correct command should be:
forge test --mt testPriceFeedVersionIsAccurate -vvv --fork-url (followed by RPC url)

where --mt is the alias of --match-test.
You can refer to more options from the Foundry doc.

thankyouu :) i was following lectures of older version

You’re welcome. Happy coding!

Kindly mark the answer as accepted if it helped you, so that it could potentially help others facing the same issue.
